# Problem with SQL, ResultSet in java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

How can I iterate ResultSet ? I've tried with the following code, but i get the error java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

```
 while ( !rs.isLast()) {
     rs.next();
     int id = rs.getInt("person_id");
     SQL.getInstance().getSt().execute("INSERT ref_person_pub(person_id) VALUES(" + id + ")");
}
```

Update: I've found the problem. I have used only one statement from the SQL singleton. When the statement is closed it can't be used again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the [JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html):

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) { 
    int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
    // ...
}
```

The [`ResultSet#next()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) moves the cursor forward one row from its current position and returns `true` if the new current row is valid. Thus, the `while` loop will stop automatically when there are no more rows.

If it is supposed to return zero or one row instead of multiple rows, then rather use `if` instead:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
if (resultSet.next()) { 
    int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
    // ...
}
```

This way you have the opportunity to add an `else`.

**Update**, that said and unrelated to the actual problem, I see more potential problems in your code: first, you seem to fire multiple queries which are dependent on each other. This can be done more efficient. Are you familiar with [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)? Second, aren't you leaking JDBC resources? It look like that you're acquiring a statement, but not getting a handle of it so that you can properly close it after use. Please consult the before linked JDBC tutorial for a basic explanation how to work properly with JDBC code and [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) for several basic kickoff examples how to use JDBC properly. Otherwise your application may crash sooner or later when the DB runs out of resources.

Comment: When I try to use rs.next() in the while statement I get the same error.

Comment: You can impossibly get `Illegal operation on empty result set` when calling `next()` on a freshly acquired resultset. So your problem lies somewhere else. Either you're accessing the wrong resultset or you're misinterpreting the exception and/or the code line where it's been caused.

Comment: If `getSt` (I suggest using full words) returns the same `Statement` then it isn't a leak. My JDBC is very rusty, are you allowed to carry on using an iterator whilst executing another statement on the `Statement` (bad analogy: mutating a collection whilst iterating over it)? Anyway, use a `PreparedStatement` rather than dynamic SQL. Edit: Second line of `Statement` API docs: "By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. "

Comment: @Tom: True, but looking at OP's skills/knowledge shown as far (no offense), I wouldn't expect him to magically close the `Statement` correctly somehow when it is finished with its tasks. I honestly also don't see proper ways to do it in the given code. Some nasty conditional checks in the `getInstance()` call maybe? No, I wouldn't do it. As per your edit: that would have thrown a different `SQLException` on `next()` and then only when another `ResultSet` is been acquired afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(rs.next()) {
   // iterate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should typically iterate through a `ResultSet` in Java:

```
try 
{     
    while (rs.next())
   {         
      int id = rs.getInt("person_id");         
   //Perform your operations here, such as inserting data into the database 
   } 
} catch (SQLException e) 
  {     
      // Handle any SQLException that might occur during iteration
  }
```

1. Always check if the ResultSet has rows using rs.next() before attempting to
   retrieve data.
2. Ensure proper error handling by catching and handling any SQLException that
   might occur during the iteration or when closing resources.