# Can't print information from SQL in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

The user must choose a Resort ID from the table that is displayed and the make a booking. I can't seem to find my problem, I want to print the name of the Resort that they are making a booking at.

```
String x = jTextFieldID.getText();
    Integer Resort = Integer.valueOf(x);
    int resort = Integer.parseInt(x);
    String sql = "SELECT RESORT_NAME FROM LouwDataBase.Resorts WHERE ID = "+Resort;  
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, resort);
                try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
                    if (rs.next()) {
                    String resortName = rs.getString("RESORT_NAME");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You want to book at " + resortName);
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what is it? The issue may be that you haven't formatted your table reference properly. The format is database.schema.table. Maybe try using LouwDatabase.dbo.Resorts (or the actual schema if it is differnt).

Comment: May 11, 2017 9:36:37 PM it.pat.Booking jButton1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Method 'executeQuery(String)' not allowed on prepared statement.
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)

Comment: The error message is quite clear: use `pstmt.executeQuery()` instead, without the string parameter.

Comment: You should psoted the Error stack with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that `sql` is passed to `Statement.executeQuery(String)` too, instead of the `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`.

```
int resort = Integer.parseInt(x);
//String sql = "SELECT RESORT_NAME FROM LouwDataBase.Resorts WHERE ID = ?";  
String sql = "SELECT RESORT_NAME FROM LouwDataBase.Resorts WHERE ID = " + resort;  
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    //pstmt.setInt(1, resort);
    try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            String resortName = rs.getString("RESORT_NAME");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "You want to book at " + resortName);
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Booking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Commented is the alternative usage of a prepared statement (as normally used).

Also you should close statement and result set, which can be done automatically with try-with-resources as above.

**Oh, oversaw almost, that `rs.next()` must be called.** (The others already mentioned.)

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: The column position '1' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '0'.

Comment: I Changed the WHERE ID = ?" to WHERE ID = "+Resort and got this error above

Comment: @Swiper if you don't share your update we can't help you, so please share your code please

Comment: Either placeholder `?` and `setInt(1,...)` or no setInt. Prepared statements are intended to be used with placeholders, https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `rs.next()` :

```
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(sql);
String resortName = "";
if(rs.next()){//<<-----------------------------
  resortName = rs.getString("RESORT_NAME");
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You want to book at "+resortName);
```

If you want to get many results you can use `while(rs.next){...}` instead.

---

Note? for a good practice, don't use upper letter in beginning for the name of your variables `ResortName` use this instead `resortName`

Comment: It's `rs.next()` and not `rs.next`, fix the typo :)

Comment: Sorry I tried using a rs.next, but got the same error. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Swiper my mistake try usinf `rs.next()` with parenthesis instead

Comment: @Swiper what DBMS you are using?

Comment: I am using the JavaDB in NetBeans.

Comment: can you please share your last modification @Swiper ?

Comment: I went back to my original, I kept getting the same error with each modification.

Answer (score 2):

You need to test over the `ResultSet` result before trying to read from it:

```
if(rs.next()) {
    String ResortName = rs.getString(1);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You want to book at "+ResortName);
}
```

And you can use `getString(1)` to get the `RESORT_NAME`, check [ResultSet **.getString(int index)** method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)) for further details.

Comment: Just tried it, don't think I need a loop, I just want to display the Resort Name of the ID the users enters

Comment: @Swiper where did I mentioned `loop` in my answer? I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry I mean the next()

Comment: Yes the test is just there to avoid getting `NullPointerException` if there's no matching result from DB.

Comment: @Swiper **`rs.next()`, it shifts the cursor to the next row of the result set from the database and returns true if there is any row, otherwise false** for that you have to use `rs.next()` read this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8199458/5558072